# iOS error with AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, audiotoolbox, avaudiosession

My users keep getting this error and I have never been able to reproduce it on the simulator or my device. I'm not implementing the AVAudioSessionDelegate (might be named differently) and I'm always using the applications default AVAudioSession, never create a new one.

Any suggestions as to what might cause it?

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x31ca5fbc objc_msgSend + 15
1   AudioToolbox 0x3677ff27 _ZN29AudioSessionPropertyListeners24CallPropertyListenersImpEmmPKv + 274
2   AudioToolbox 0x36780205 _ZN29AudioSessionPropertyListeners21CallPropertyListenersEmmPKv + 240
3   AudioToolbox 0x3677de81 SSServer_AudioSessionInterruptionListenerMessage + 56
4   AudioToolbox 0x36726483 _XAudioSessionInterruptionListenerMessage + 62
5   AudioToolbox 0x366bb373 mshMIGPerform + 374
6   CoreFoundation 0x38199553 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
7   CoreFoundation 0x381994f5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
8   CoreFoundation 0x38198343 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
9   CoreFoundation 0x3811b4dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
10  CoreFoundation 0x3811b3a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
11  GraphicsServices 0x37c99fcd GSEventRunModal + 156
12  UIKit 0x355ab743 UIApplicationMain + 1090
13  Accentuate! 0x395f main (main.m:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

We've just been tracking a very similar crash.

Ours turn out to be as described here:

https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/issues/6

In particular, MyAudioSessionInterruptionListener (or the name of the callback passed to 
AudioSessionInitialize) and it's inClientData can not be changed after it's been registered, so the callback must always do something sensible even if the underlying object has been deallocated.

The solution suggested for AudioStream is to use a static variable, and make sure it points to the object that is currently interested in the callback, and never points at a deallocated object - the important thing is not to use inClientData.